# Simple Xamarin Studio add-in empty project template issues

Tags: templates, xamarin, monodevelop, add-in, xamarin-studio

I'm trying to create simple project template add-in in Xamarin Studio using "Addin Maker" addin (version 1.3.2). Addin project reference  Monodevelop.Addins package (version 0.3.9).

I have simple Manifest.addin.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ExtensionModel>

    <Runtime>
        <Import file="Templates/EmptyTemplate.xpt.xml"/>
    </Runtime>

    <Extension path="/MonoDevelop/Ide/ProjectTemplates">
        <ProjectTemplate id="EmptyTemplate" file="Templates/EmptyTemplate.xpt.xml"/>
    </Extension>
</ExtensionModel>
```

EmptyTemplate.xpt.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Template>
    <TemplateConfiguration>
        <_Name>Test</_Name>
        <Category>crossplat/app/forms</Category>
    </TemplateConfiguration>
    <Actions>
    </Actions>
    <Combine name="test" directory=".">
        <Options>
            <StartupProject>test</StartupProject>
        </Options>
        <Project name="test" directory=".">
            <References>
            </References>
            <Packages>
            </Packages>
            <Files>
            </Files>
        </Project>
    </Combine>
</Template>
```

The add-in can be installed, without issues, into XS using launch/debug addin project or by creating mpack file in the terminal. Unfortunately my test project template is not visible under Multiplatform/App/Xamarin.Forms or Other/Miscellaneous/Generis New Project dialog.

When launching New Project dialog following entry can be found in the log:

```
Loaded assembly: /Applications/Xamarin Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/BackendBindings/MonoDevelop.VBNetBinding.dll [External]
INFO [2017-02-20 13:16:17Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.ILAsmBinding
INFO [2017-02-20 13:16:17Z]: Add-in loaded: test.test
Loaded assembly: /Applications/Xamarin Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/BackendBindings/ILAsmBinding.dll [External]
```

Plugin is also visible in XS addin manager under IDE Extensions section.

What is wrong with this simple template add-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In your `Manifest.addin.xml` remove the `<Runtime></Runtime>` section.

2) Since you are using "file=" references for your templates make sure that the **Build Action** of those template files are set to **`AddinFile`**

#### Example `Properties/Manifest.addin.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ExtensionModel>
    <Extension path="/MonoDevelop/Ide/ProjectTemplates">
        <ProjectTemplate id="RealmEmptyProject" file="templates/PsEmptyProject.xpt.xml" />
    </Extension>
</ExtensionModel>
```

#### Example Template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Template Originator="SushiHangover">
    <TemplateConfiguration>
        <Icon>md-project</Icon>
        <LanguageName>C#</LanguageName>
        <_Name>Realm (Viper) Project</_Name>
        <Category>other/net/general</Category>
        <_Description>Creates an empty Realm Database Viper (MVVM-hybrid) project</_Description>
        <DefaultFilename>RealmViperProject</DefaultFilename>
        <GroupId>md-realm-project</GroupId>
    </TemplateConfiguration>

    <Combine name="${ProjectName}" directory=".">
        <Project name="${ProjectName}" directory=".">
            <References>
                <Reference type="Package" refto="System" LocalCopy="false" SpecificVersion="true" />
            </References>
            <Packages>
                <package id="Realm" />
            </Packages>
        </Project>
    </Combine>
</Template>
```

[image]

Comment: I think the Runtime import section is needed otherwise the file will not added to the .mpack when you run mdtool setup pack.

Comment: @MattWard The runtime section gets auto-generated into the `obj/Debug/_Manifest.addin.xml` file and thus the files are included in the Addin `.mpack`, including it in the project's `Manifest.addin.xml` causes my Template Addins to fail.... Should it not? (maybe if you are creating addin by hand and not with MHutch's addin... it been a long time since I manually created one.. ;-)

Comment: Thanks. My mistake. I obviously do not use the Addin Maker enough with my own addins :)

Comment: @MattWard lol... I'm always learning and finding something in Xamarin that I did not know, I know my way "works", but if there is a "better way" I'm all ears, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1) Thanks for the @sushihangover answer. It was also a part of my problem.

In my scenario it also worked with `<Runtime>` section and with every Build action as long as Copy to Output Directory for xpt file was selected.

2) I've also noticed that plugins installed using "play" option from one XS instance to the new debug instance was not always clean installed/uninstalled. So when I was playing for example with one of the options in my xpt it wasn't taken into account until I manually uninstalled add-in from the new debug XS instance and clean the project.

3) Above scenario has probably happened when I was playing with `<GroupId>` section found in original Xamarin.Forms template delivered with XS. I copied `<GroupId>md-xamarin-forms-project</GroupId>` from their template to my test xpt so it was not able to populate second template for the same `<LanguageName>`. I was not able to make it work until `<GroupId>` section was removed, add-in was uninstalled and project was cleaned up.